# How can I tell if there's an electrical issue or if I have a bad dryer?

Tags: electrical, dryer, 240v

I purchased a [dryer from Sears](http://www.sears.com/kenmore-6.5-cu-ft-electric-dryer-white/p-02661402000P): recently, which didn't work upon being connected. I performed a couple electrical checks (more on that in a moment), then called them up and told them that it was dead on arrival. They delivered another one, which also didn't work. I'm trying to figure out if the problem is electrical or just dead dryers.

Our box is a 3 wire, 30 amp 220/240VAC.

What I have tested with my multimeter (both at the outlet and at the dryer):

1. Line1 to Line2: ~240V
2. Line1 to Neutral: ~120V
3. Line2 to Neutral: ~120V
4. Neutral to Ground: 0V

[image: Outside box]

[image: Inside box]

Comment: Have you checked for blown fuses? Was there a previously a dryer that was working?

Comment: I'm measuring the voltage after the fuses so I don't think it's a blown fuse. The place is new to me and I'm not sure if there was a dryer there previously. Thanks

Comment: Can you spin the inside of the dryer with nominal force? Is the door closing all the way / checked the interlock? Are the controls moving freely?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible it is the dryers, but not likely.  You have checked the socket for the source of the problem and it doesn't seem to be there.  Next check the cord you are using and double check the wiring of the cord to the dryer.

Comment: I've checked the voltage at before the fuses all the way down to inside the electrical panel of the dryer, so I'm sure that the cord isn't the issue. Thank, what's the next step from here?

Comment: double check install instructions and if everything looks good, then assume very poor quality control on the dryer.

Comment: Also post a picture of the dryer electrical panel.  I know I miss stupid things all the time and another set of eyes are always good.  Edit...  I see you have pictures but the network I'm on is blocking them.

Comment: Unfortunately the photos that are being blocked are the electrical panel.

Comment: I just figured it out but I can't post the answer yet... no connect in the receptacle neutral wire. I was still able to measure voltage in spite of this, but it failed the continuity check. Thanks for your help.